# Select data from a table from database when a particular tableView row is clicked

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am doing a quiz application.
In the first screen, I have a table view which has 5 rows in it stating chapter1, chapter2....etc.
I'm using `SQLite` as my database, it consists of 5 tables in it.

So when I select row 1 in the `UITableView` which corresponds to chapter1, it should load chapter1 into my array from database, and if select row 2 in the `UITableView` which corresponds to chapter2, it should load chapter2 into my array from database and so on....

How should I create references?

Answer (score 0):

This should be an easy one: just use UITableView's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // load from database using indexPath.row as the number of your chapter 
    // and display whatever you want to display
}
```